# Deploying Depot App to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

I've been reading Agile web development with Rails and i got to the point where i have to deploy my app to Heroku. The thing is my app is working normally in local but when i deploy it it shows just a layout without database content(products cart..). I've been following ruby on rails tutorial by michael hartl in order to deploy my app to heroku since the first book does it with capistrano. I've made some changes in gemfile and database.yml since I've been using sqlite3 all along

Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do

  gem 'sqlite3'

  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :production do

  gem 'pg'

end

database.yml:

default: &default

  adapter: sqlite3

  pool: 5

  timeout: 5000

development:

  <<: *default

  database: db/development.sqlite3

  <<: *default

  database: db/test.sqlite3


production:

  adapter: postgresql

  database: depot_production
```

First after deployment i got we re sorry something went wrong message
then i ran heroku run rake db:migrate and restart
and then i got just a front-end layout without products catalog and cart

Comment: Firstly, use heroku logs, it will tell you what's going wrong, next, if I'm not mistaken, heroku uses postreSQL as the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've just deployed your app for the first time, the database in Heroku will be empty. Running `rake db:migrate` creates the tables, indexes, etc specified in your migrations, but does not fill these tables with any data. You'll have to do that yourself. If you just want data for testing purposes, one options is to take advantage of the `rails db:seeds` task.

> To add initial data after a database is created, Rails has a built-in
>   'seeds' feature that makes the process quick and easy. This is
>   especially useful when reloading the database frequently in
>   development and test environments. It's easy to get started with this
>   feature: just fill up db/seeds.rb with some Ruby code, and run `rails db:seed`

([docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data))

Comment: Yes I forgot to seed the data. Thank you.